# Entry time and hitting time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Hi I have a question about entry time and hitting time.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $(X_{t})_{t \in[0,\infty)}$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-valued  stochastic process on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$. Let $U$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. For $U$,we define the first entry time of $U$ by 
\begin{align*}
D_{U}=\inf \{t \geq 0\,:\,X_{t} \in U \}
\end{align*}
and the first hitting time of $U$ by
\begin{align*}
T_{U}=\inf \{t > 0\,:\,X_{t} \in U \}
\end{align*}

where in both cases th  infimum of the empty set is understood to be $\infty$.

We suppose $(X_{t})_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is right continuous. i.e. $\forall \omega \in \Omega$ , $t \mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$ is right continuous.

In this case, I can understand $D_{U} \leq T_{U}$ (I used the definition of inifimum)

But $D_{U}=T_{U}$ is so clear? I can't understand this.

I am trying to prove $\{t \geq 0\,:\,X_{t}(\omega) \in U  \} \subset \{t > 0\,:\,X_{t}(\omega) \in U \} $.

Let $s \in \{t \geq 0\,:\,X_{t} \in U  \} $, but if $s=0$ then $s \notin \{t > 0\,:\,X_{t}(\omega) \in U \}   $. If you know a different method, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am trying to prove $\{t \geq 0\,:\,X_{t}(\omega) \in U \} \subset \{t>0\,:\,X_{t}(\omega) \in U\}$.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, let us say you try to prove this. And... `where is the problem when you try to show this?`

Comment: Oh...sorry I stop this approach. But I maybe understand. Cleary $T_{U}=D_{U}$ on $\{X_{0} \notin U \}$. On $\{X_{0} \in U \}$ $D_{U}=0$. By using the right continuity of $t \mapsto X_{t}(\omega)$, for all $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N$,$|X_{\frac{1}{n}}-X_{0}|<\epsilon$. this implies $T_{U} \leq \frac{1}{n}$. We get $T_{U} \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}=0$ Is that right?

Comment: Yes--provided your N depends on ω.

Comment: Sorry I should have been thinking more.